# Spawning Multiple Bullets

Tags: c++, directx, game-development

To be Honest this was a test given to me when I applied to Game Dev Job 2 years ago but I failed to solve this specific problem back then I need Instruction on how can I achieve spawning multiple bullets.

```
void Game::SpawnBullet(XMVECTOR position, XMVECTOR direction)
{
    DeleteBullet();

    bullet_ = new Bullet(position, direction);
    bullet_->EnableCollisions(collision_, 3.0f);
}
void Game::UpdatePlayer(System* system)
{
  if (keyboard->IsKeyPressed(VK_SPACE))
     {
    XMVECTOR playerForward = player_->GetForwardVector();
    XMVECTOR bulletPosition = player_->GetPosition() + playerForward * 10.0f;
    SpawnBullet(bulletPosition, playerForward);
     }
}

void Game::UpdateBullet(System* system)
{
  if (bullet_ != NULL)
     {
       bullet_->Update(system);
       WrapEntity(bullet_);
     }
}
```

I Tried Calling Spawn Multiple times with Different location and Direction but it doesn't seems to Update. A friend Told me to call function multiple times, store result in vector instead of one pointer but aim not sure how.

Comment: From the look of `Game::SpawnBullet` the game code only supports one bullet at a time `bullet_`. So starting point is to change `bullet_` into a vector of `Bullet` and then fix all the code that does not compile. Then set some limits on max number of bullets and how many game-ticks a bullet can live for to stop bullet spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `SpawnBullet` starts off like this:

```cpp
void Game::SpawnBullet(XMVECTOR position, XMVECTOR direction)
{
    DeleteBullet();
```

...the first step toward supporting multiple bullets is probably going to be eliminating that `DeleteBullet()` call, which (apparently) deletes any existing bullet when you try to spawn a new one.

Beyond that, you'll undoubtedly want to change the existing `bullet_` variable from a single pointer to something like a `vector`.

`UpdateBullet` will also need to be updated so instead of updating a single bullet, it updates all the bullets in the `vector` (or whatever collection you choose, but probably `vector`).

Comment: Thanks men, Will Update the code as per your suggestion.